# Is there a way to iterate through a commma seperated list and a create a new list with single entries in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, string, split, iteration

I've got an array list like this :

```
| serialNumbers   |  Date      |
| --------------- | ---------- |
| 543545, 235524  | 2022/07/23 |
| 213422          | 2022/10/11 |
| 342404, 324352  | 2021/08/03 |
| 213422          | 2022/10/11 |
```

How do I create a list like this where entries with multiple serial numbers are seperated into their own entries in javascript or SQL? I'm getting the data from sql into react so is there any way in either sql or JS to do that? I know there is .split() method in JS but I'm not sure how to implement it with this array

expected result:

```
| serialNumbers   |  Date      |
| --------------- | ---------- |
| 543545          | 2022/07/23 |
| 235524          | 2022/07/23 |
| 213422          | 2022/10/11 |
| 324352          | 2021/08/03 |
| 324352          | 2021/08/03 |
| 213422          | 2022/10/11 |
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64588324/split-array-element-in-two-elements-using-javascript might be helpful to you

Comment: You need to show some code at least with the array because what you posted isn't an array

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show how your data stored in DB, also mark RDMS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Javascript` you can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do it,waiting for a solution using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do it

```js
const arr =[
    {
      "serialNumbers": "543545, 235524",
      "Date": '2022/07/23'
    },
    {
      "serialNumbers": "213422",
      "Date": '2022/10/11'
    },
    {
      "serialNumbers": "342404, 324352",
      "Date": '2021/08/03'
    },
    {
      "serialNumbers": "213422",
      "Date": '2022/10/11 '
    }
]


const res = arr.reduce((acc,val) =>{
  let nums = val.serialNumbers.split(",")
  for(num of nums){
   acc.push({"serialNumbers":num.trim(),"Date":val.Date})
   }
  return acc
},[]);

console.log(res)
```